# Numeric comparisons such as greater-than on a currency amount stored as a string

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have an example JSON file with fake bank users, and I want to find the people with a balance greater than $1000, how can I do so? Do keep in mind the balance is a String value.
EXAMPLE USER INFO:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("58d1cae3cba624106c8080ab"),
    "isActive" : false,
    "balance" : "$3,495.58",
    "age" : 24,
    "eyeColor" : "blue",
    "name" : "Webster Sanders",
    "gender" : "male",
    "company" : "HALAP",
    "email" : "webstersanders@halap.com",
    "phone" : "+1 (883) 536-2259",
    "address" : "300 Jewel Street, Sugartown, Federated States Of Micronesia, 9305"
}
```

Comment: Are you going to use the command inside an application or just a single run in the mongo shell?

Comment: @ThomasBormans in a mongo shell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression like:

```
db.users.find({ balance: { $regex: /^\$[1-9][0-9\,]{3,}/ } });
```

Comment: im sorry but can you explain to me what the command / expression does?

Comment: The regex works by making sure the first number is greater than 1 and that it is followed by 3 or more numbers. So to break it down: ^ means from the start of the line. \$ matches the $ symbol. [1-9] matches the numbers from 1 to 9. [0-9] matches all numbers. {3,} match the previous pattern at least 3 times.

Comment: I have edited the regular expression to handle the ',' in the balance ([0-9\,]). It should work now.

Answer (score 0):

You are making life very difficult for yourself by storing the monetary value as a string. You would be better off [storing it as a numeric value, possibly with a string equivalent (for presentation) in a second field if necessary](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/model-monetary-data/).

Answer (score 0):

Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

Comment: var currency = "-$4,400.50";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

Answer (score 0):

please try below code

var currency = "-$4,400.50";
var number = Number(currency.replace(/[^0-9.-]+/g,""));

Answer (score -1):

First get balance in string, and then replace `$` and `,` with '' (blank quotes) then use `int.parse`.

For example :

```
string a = balance
a = a.replace("$","");
a = a.replace(",","");
int balance = int.parse(a);
```

Comment: im not using  a proper lang, im using commands: https://gyazo.com/e99fa8215cd8b90d19d2fab7dd4680fc